# How to expand tab character in TListBox.OnDrawItem event based on TListBox.TabWidth property?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi XE4 and below is my sample application.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    procedure ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect;
        State: TOwnerDrawState);
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses System.Math;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  ListBox1.Style := lbOwnerDrawVariable;

  ListBox1.Items.Add('o'#9'Line 1');
  ListBox1.Items.Add('o'#9'Line 2');
  ListBox1.Items.Add('o'#9'Line 3');
  ListBox1.Items.Add('o'#9'Line 4');
  ListBox1.Items.Add('o'#9'Line 5');
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect:
    TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
const C: array[boolean] of TColor = (clRed, clGreen);
var L: TListBox;
    S: string;
    iTextHeight: integer;
begin
  L := Control as TListBox;
  L.Canvas.Font.Color := C[Index < 2];

  S := L.Items[Index];

  iTextHeight := Max(Rect.Height, L.Canvas.TextHeight(S) + 2);
  SendMessage(L.Handle, LB_SETITEMHEIGHT, Index, iTextHeight);
  Rect.Height := iTextHeight;
  L.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);

  L.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left, Rect.Top + 1, S);
end;

end.
```

The purpose of using TListBox.OnDrawItem event is to show some items with different font colour in my real application. Is there any way to expand the tab character in TListBox.DrawItem event based on TListBox.TabWidth?

Comment: Do not set item height when drawing. Items should be measured in the `OnMeasureItem` event before.

Comment: DrawText[Ex] can expand tabs.

Comment: I have tried this code: DrawText(L.Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), S.Length, Rect, DT_EXPANDTABS); but the tab character expand with an "unknown/fixed" tab width instead of TListBox.TabWidth.

Comment: By default it's 8 chars wide (hard to say which chars though), but you can affect that by the [`DT_TABSTOP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx#DT_TABSTOP) flag (see the linked description how). However, why do you overcomplicate this with tabs anyway ? You can simply draw two texts per item. That's precise and doesn't rely on that *magical* char width.

Comment: @lmengyew - Also try the documents, you can specify tab widths. But you'll need to convert from pixels.

Comment: @TLama - In my real application, 'o' represents 'old', only some items have the indicator of 'o', the rest of items have a space as indicator. All items not in pretty align if not based on tab width.

Comment: @TLama, Sertac Akyuz - After go through the linked document, this code works for me: P.cbSize := SizeOf(P); P.iTabLength := 5; P.iLeftMargin := 0; P.iRightMargin := 0; DrawTextEx(L.Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), S.Length, Rect, DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_TABSTOP, @P);

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can post and accept your own answer with solution that you used if you want. But if I were you I would leave this tab magic and go for separate rendering for each *column*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me.

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect:
    TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var //...
    P: TDrawTextParams;
begin
  //...

  P.cbSize := SizeOf(P);
  P.iTabLength := 5;
  P.iLeftMargin := 0;
  P.iRightMargin := 0;
  DrawTextEx(L.Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), S.Length, Rect, DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_TABSTOP, @P);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Basically use the tab width to work out where things should be painted. The code below would replace your last `TextOut` call. I am stripping out the tabs and whenever I encounter one I am indenting the output by the listbox tab width:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect:
    TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var 
  LeftIndent: Integer;
begin
  ...

  LeftIndent := 0;
  while Pos(#9,S) > 0 do
  begin
    L.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + LeftIndent, Rect.Top + 1, Copy(S, 1, Pos(#9,S)-1));
    Delete(S, 1, Pos(#9,S));
    LeftIndent := LeftIndent + L.TabWidth;
  end;
  L.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + LeftIndent, Rect.Top + 1, S);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, anyway. I have found the solution using DrawTextEx.